# Searching in MongoID using a variable as key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am using Mongoid in a Rails application. Let's said there is a model called `Product`. Each `product` document have some fields that the other document don't have. Here are 2 examples.

```
{name: "Product A", color: "Yellow", discount: "0.9"}
{name: "Product B", color: "Blue", size: "XXL"}
```

The field `discount` or `size` may changed from time to time. Assumed I have a form that let users to search by the field name (i.e. `discount`) and value. How can I pass the variable that contains the field name to a Mongoid Criteria?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
@return_value = Model.where("field_name"=>"value").all
```

For your problem use

```
@value = Product.where("discount" => ".0.9").all
```

Comment: But the word "discount" may be changed, so I stored a list of key somewhere else. Is it possible that use a variable in the criteria?

Comment: You can use the variable(field_name) that are included in model file as field.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. I will have a try.